# How to group DataTable results using Linq query expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following DataTable

```
DataTable BookTable = new DataTable();
//Add columns in Book Table
BookTable.Columns.Add("BookCategory", typeof(string));
BookTable.Columns.Add("BookName", typeof(string));
//Add rows in Book Table
BookTable.Rows.Add( "Programming", "C# basics");
BookTable.Rows.Add("Programming", "Java basics");
BookTable.Rows.Add("Networking", "Networking Basics");
BookTable.Rows.Add("Database", "Intro to Database");
```

I want to filter out Book Names on the basis of Book Category Column for this i have written the following Lambda expression

```
var BooksList = from Book in BookTable.AsEnumerable()
                group Book by Book.Field<string>("BookCategory") into g
                let list = g.ToList()
                select new
                {
                    BookCategory = g.Key,

                    BookNames = list.Select(x => x.Field<string>("BookName").ToString())                  };
```

Now I have to print the out put in the following format;

1. Programming

   - C# basics
   - Java basics
2. Networking

   - Networking Basics
3. Database

   - Intro to Database

I am interested in knowing how can i obtain the Book Names from book Categories in the following code;

```
foreach(var Book in BooksList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Book.BookCategory);
    //logic to Obtain Book Names Here ;
}
```

Comment: Um... `Book.BookNames` ?!

Comment: its is returning :  
` {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<System.Data.DataRow, string>} `  Not Book Names print in String.

Comment: in your shown code you have uncommented the `.Where`, so why do you get a `WhereSelectListIterator`? Is it not the real code? Also, What code do you have tried, what is causing this exception(is it an exception at all?)?

Comment: Yes, its a lazy iterator, just an inner foreach around it

Comment: i have tried the following code to print the values                                       `foreach(var Book in BooksList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Book.BookCategory);
               Console.WriteLine(Book.BookNames);
            }`

Comment: Well, `Book.BookNames` is not a single string but multiple. So you either need another loop or something like `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Book.BookNames));`

Comment: Thanks for your help it is working.
i f you would like to post it as an answer Please paste it i will mark it as correct to add to your profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need insert String.Join in your code:

```
var BooksList = from Book in BookTable.AsEnumerable()
                        group Book by Book.Field<string>("BookCategory") into g
                        let list = g.ToList()
                        select new
                        {
                            BookCategory = g.Key,

                            BookNames = string.Join(" ; ",list.Select(x => x.Field<string>("BookName").ToString()))
                        };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.